# how to know that my android application downloaded from which site where I gave advertisement of my app

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, tracking

How to know that my android application downloaded from which site where I gave advertisement of my android application ?
For example I gave my android application advertisement on facebook, twitter, Linkdin and other shopping websites.So user saw my app and click on my app icon to download and the user went to google play store via that ads and download it.
So how developer know that from which ads sites how many downloads happen?
Is it any way to know about it..????

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about marketing. See the help center for more information on how to ask on-topic questions.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the closest you'd get to achieving this would be to use the Google Play Referral Campaign Measurement as mentioned here: http://techcrunch.com/2013/10/03/google-gives-android-developers-improved-analytics-to-track-users-acquisition-and-engagement-data/

Detailed info can be obtained from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-campaigns

Generate campaign tracking variables and append them to the URLs for the ads you place on advertisers' sites. When the users click on your ads, the campaign data gets sent to your site and recorded by the Google Play Campaign Measurement. You can use the URL tool builder to create this URLs for your ads - it's quite simple to do. You can then create a goal on your site and view the segment of users who have come from the individual campaigns, which will show the number of visits, page views and conversions for each campaign.

Also check this link to know the working of Install-Referrer: http://support.mobileapptracking.com/entries/22561636-How-Google-Play-Install-Referrer-Works